# How to create a regex VBA macro for GIIN format validation

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that will verify data in one column and then let me know if they are correctly formatted in the next column. I am very new to VBA so I apologize if my code is messy.

The format I am trying to verify is ABC123.AB123.AB.123 -- The first two sections can contain letters/numbers, the third section only letters, and the last section only numbers.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
Function ValidGIIN(myGIIN As String) As String
    Dim regExp As Object

    Set regExp = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")

    If Len(myGIIN) Then
            .Global = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_][.][a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_][.][a-zA-z_][a-zA-z_][.][0-9][0-9][0-9]"

        End With

        If regExp.Test(myGIIN) = True Then
            ValidGIIN = "Valid"
        Else
            ValidGIIN = "Invalid"

        End If
    End If
    Set regExp = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Does the order of numbers/letters matter? I assume ABC stands for anything a-zA-Z ?so both cases should be covered? Likewise 123 being 0-9? And what isn't working with your code?

Comment: The order of the numbers/letters do not matter. Your assumption is correct.

Comment: And the . exist? And where can  contain numbers and letters do you mean must have at least one of each?

Comment: They can contain either a letter OR number for those sections.

Comment: Ok... are the "." actually present for the pattern? And can there be anything before or after this pattern? For example, is it sufficient with  [a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\.[A-Za-z]{2}\.\d{3}

Comment: Correct, the "." are present for the pattern. For example, one correctly formatted would look like "G0H3T3.LF83H.AH.123".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following pattern

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\.[A-Za-z]{2}\.\d{3}
```

You could call your function in a loop over cells in a column and use offset(0,1) to write result to next column to right.